# How to set focus for an Entry in Xamarin.Forms targeting UWP platform?

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, focus, master-detail, xamarin.forms.entry

I have created an application using `Xamarin.Forms` targeting `Android` and `UWP` platforms. (UWP on the Desktop, not the phone).
I am using a Master/Details navigation, which on UWP stays open when navigating from a page to another. In the main page and only on UWP I've got an `Entry` that I want to Focus when the view is appearing, so I did this:

```
protected override void ViewIsAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.ViewIsAppearing(sender, e);
    Device.OnPlatform(WinPhone: () =>
    {
        CustomComponent.GainFocus();
    });
}
```

Inside my CustomComponent which is StackLayout actually, I have this:

```
public void GainFocus()
{
    CustomEntry.Focus();
}
```

My problem is when I navigate to `Page2` or `Page3` for example and come back to the `MainPage` the function is getting called, but the entry is never being focused and the focus stays in the Navigation Panel on the clicked item from the navigation list. **How can I fix this so my `Entry` always gets the focus?**

#### Edit:

I have made some debugging to know what's going on.
I added handler for `Focused` and `Unfocused` to my `CustomEntry`

```
private void CustomEntry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CustomEntry_Unfocused");
}

private void CustomEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs focusEventArgs)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CustomEntry_Focused");
}
```

After adding this I ran my application and checked the output.
`ViewIsAppearing` > Calls Focused.
Clicking outside the entry > Calls Unfocused
Navigating away from the main page to another one > **Doesn't call Unfocused**, and returning to the main page after that > **Doesn't call Focused**
If `CustomEntry` wasn't focused and I navigate away from the main page and come back > Calls Focused.

#### Edit2:

I tried forcing `Unfocus` in the `OnViewIsDisappearing` event this way:

```
protected override void ViewIsDisappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.ViewIsDisappearing(sender, e);
    Device.OnPlatform(WinPhone: () =>
    {
        CustomComponent.LoseFocus();
    });
}
```

And inside the custom component:

```
public void LoseFocus()
{
    CustomEntry.Unfocus();
}
```

After trying this, it doesn't call `Unfocused` as well..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

> `CustomEntry.Focus();`

After `InitializeComponent();` of your desired page.

Comment: This is a simple fix ,Karan is right I'll give him an upvote ,sad to see a downvote just because it's a simple answer often times it is.